# How to display a Textview in the lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to display a message in the lock screen like this but i don't know exactly how to develop this [image]

please help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but it can be done by creating an alarm type...

```
String message = "This is a test";
Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, message);
```

You can also browse through this project to see how they did it.

http://code.google.com/p/contactowner/

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but it didn't work, and the project seems too complicated just to display a simple message. Is there a simple idea to do it. I'm thinking of the possibility to use a widget but i want it to be shown automatically.